# replace solid color in transparent PNG with imagick or GD

Tags: colors, gd, imagick

I just have a transparent PNG with star graphic in a solid color, let's say #FF0000;
What can I do to replace or convert to any hex color my user chooses?
I looked on PHP but after trying lot's of code, nothing seems to work? (for almost all of the imagick functions on PHP.net I get a warning, "This function is currently not documented")

On my server I run PHP Version 5.2.5

imagick module version : 2.1.1 
ImageMagick version: ImageMagick 6.4.1

GD Version: bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the star graphic is a uniform color, you can use the following function:

```
function recolorStar($filename, $color) {
    $img = new Imagick($filename);
    $img->colorizeImage($color, 0.0);
    header('content-type: image/png');
    echo $img;
}
```

$color should be specified in the RGB hex format, e.g. "#00FF00".

You can modify the last couple lines if you don't want to output it directly to the browser.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but it does not work, unfortunately :-(

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, or just doesn't work at all? I tested it on my dev machine and it worked fine.

Comment: mmm now it did change the color when I saved in as a PNG24, but no transparency, with a white background. Could I change the color of the background? So I don't need the transparency? cheers

Comment: I can use a PNG32 with transparency when I set the $opacity param to 0.0 $img->colorizeImage($color, 0.0); But when I change the red star in for example #CCCCCC I get a mixture or red and CCCCCC

Comment: Hey I found it :-) If instead of the red star as the base I use black it all works fine! PNG32 with transparency setting the opacity param to 0.0 Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! The Imagick PHP extension is a tricky beast that no one knows quite how to use, so a lot of trial-and-error is required. I was still searching through the docs to find something that worked. lol

Comment: I've modified the original solution with your fixes included.

Comment: If your source image isn't black, you can make it black with `$img->modulateImage(0, 0, 0);`. I know of no faster way to turn the image black while leaving alpha channel untouched.